# VueJs: bind `v-on` on a custom component to replace an existing one

Tags: vue.js, attributes

In order to ease the styling of my page, I'd like to create a bunch of mini components like, and exploit how attributes are merged in VueJs. So for example, here is a minimal js file also hosted on this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5pstc7n/1/):

```
Vue.component('my-button', {
    template: '<button style="font-size:20pt;"><slot></slot></button>'
})

var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
  data: {
    message: "world",
  },
  methods: {
    sayHello: function () {
        alert("Hello");
    }
  }
})
```

and then in my html I just want to use `<my-button>` instead of `button`:

```
<div id="app">
Hello {{message}} <my-button @click="sayHello" style="color:red;">Style works, but not click</my-button> <button v-on:click="sayHello" style="color:red;">Both works</button>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, it seems that attributes are merged, but not listeners, so it means that I can't do `v-on:click` on my new button... Any way to make it possible?

Thanks!

-- EDIT --
I saw the proposition of Boussadjra Brahim of using `.native`, and it works, but then I found [this link](https://fr.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Relier-des-evenements-natifs-aux-composants) that explains why it's not a great practice and how to use `v-on="$listeners"` to map all listeners to a specific sub-button. However, I tried, to just change my template with:

```
    template: `<button style="font-size:20pt;" v-on="$listeners"><slot></slot></button>`,
```

but I get an error:

```
Vue warn: Property or method "$listeners" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option."
```

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8dm74rn1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle didn't work because you were using an old version of Vue, `$listeners` was added in Vue 2.4.0.

Here's a demo:

```js
Vue.component('my-button', {
  template: '<button style="color: red" v-on="$listeners"><slot/></button>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    sayHello() {
      alert('Hello')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-button @click="sayHello">Custom Button</my-button>
  <button @click="sayHello">Ordinary Button</button>
</div>
```